# Swift 4.1: SelectRow for UIPickerView does not raise the delegate didSelectRow

Tags: ios, swift

The page loads the picker view data and is `UITextView` inputView is set. However when the page loads, when I set the `selectedRow` of the pickerView to the value from the DB, I expect below delegate to be raised.

```
pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
```

A workaround is mentioned that says to add a dummy row as the first row, however if that is not an option and there is only one row, is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: If you need this method specifically, why not calling it yourself?

Comment: When you set it programatically it won't call delegate methods. You have to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview) (emphasis mine):

> Called by the picker view when the ***user*** selects a row in a component.

Which means that the method will not be called if you use *code* to select a row, which presumably is what you are trying to do here ("I set the selectedRow of the pickerView to the value from the DB").

If you want to call `didSelectRow` so badly, just call it!

```
pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: yourRow, inComponent: yourComponent)
```

Alternatively, if you don't like to call delegate methods yourself, since they are not "supposed" to be called by other class, you could extract the code in the delegate method into your own method, and then call that.

Comment: Ideally it should raise the event didSelectRow even if the user re-selects the selected item (because the event is not didChangedSelection) your simple approach did save the replication of code.